# " instalar plugin usando plug.vim para nvim(neovim) " en windows10(PowerShell)

Tags: windows10, powershell, plugin, vim

ya publique una pregunta hace poco donde tenia errores al instalar plug que ahora ya lo solucione; pero tengo otro problema al intentar instalar un plugin para neovim :

le doy así como GitHub lo indica, **este es mi powershell** :

```html
1 call plug3begin()
2
3 Plug 'dikiaap/minimalist'
4
5 call plug3end()
6
7 establecer  t_Co = 256
8 sintaxis  en
9 esquema de colores minimalista
```

**y al presionar enter sale:**  los siguientes errores: que desconoce las funciones que puse que indican en GitHub, por que ?

```html
Se ha detectado un error al procesar D:\Users\kraud\AppData\Local\nvim\init.vim:
línea    1
E117: Función desconocida: plug3begin
línea    3
E492: No es una orden del editor: Plug 'dikiaap/minimalist'
línea    5
E117: Función desconocida: plug3end
línea    7
E492: No es una orden del editor: establecer  t_Co = 256
línea    8
E33: No existe una expresión regular de sustitución previa
línea    9
E492: No es una orden del editor: esquema de colores minimalista
Pulse INTRO o escriba una orden para continuar
```

no sé si falte instalar "Git";  pero también ya lo instale y sigue el error.  **instale Git pero no se si hay que vincular de alguna forma a neovim... y si es eso no sé como hacerlo... ayuda!!!**

Comment: no es plug3begin...es plug#begin...lo mismo para el plug#end

Comment: si exactamente, ya me di cuenta xd. gracias           . pero ahora hay otro problema que powershell no reconoce #,  y lo pone como 3 ;  joder!!!       jajaja no se como hacer que reconozca..

Comment: Bueno no he manejado nvim, solo vim, pero hasta donde se es casi lo mismo, asi que no se porque utilizarias el powershell para instalar los plugins, eso lo haces desde nvim mismo, y otra cosa, veo que tienes los comandos para establecer el tema y colores en español, lo cual deberia estar en ingles, tu lo traduciste solo para realizar la pregunta o están asi realmente en tu archivo de configuración ?

Comment: sisi, se me paso quise decir nvim:   nvim no reconoce  #

Comment: Otra cosa que veo es que no estás estableciendo la ruta donde se van a descargar o instalar los plugins eso lo configuras en call begin#plug('ruta')... por lo general es call begin#plug('~/.vim/plugged') en mi caso para vim

Comment: Y si, tambien necesitas instalar git, ya que vim plug descarga los plugins desde los repositorios de git.

Comment: ya instale Git; pero solamente lo instalo? o se vincul(configura ,no sè...) a nvim

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112763/discussion-between-soyunewok-and-kraud).

Answer (score 0):

Cuando estás con teclado en español, *nvim* no reconoce el **#**, cambias el teclado a inglés y con <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> sale el **#**.